# What is the story for creating and consuming TypeScript libraries?

Tags: typescript, libraries

I've been using TypeScript here and there for web applications and have referenced public type definitions made available through [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped) but one thing that has always eluded me is how one would go about creating reusable libraries in TypeScript with the purpose of being consumed by a TypeScript application or another library.

Most guidance on the topic seems to point directly to how one would create or find type definitions for libraries authored originally in JavaScript but what about libraries written in TypeScript, it seems that some mechanism for sharing the resulting js files and a corresponding type definition file should be something that is common place but I haven't been able to find any mention of anybody trying to do this for private or public libraries. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places? Is there a story for creating and consuming TypeScript libraries.

Comment: The new Angular 2 is built from scratch using TypeScript. You can take a look at the git hub repository to find out what to do.

Comment: I use [my own small library](https://github.com/ArtemAvramenko/propjet.js) written in TS. It can be loaded via NuGet or Bower with both `d.ts` and `js` at once.

Comment: I've thought about looking at Angular 2 but I wasn't sure whether they expose their type definition files as part of their regular client facing package or whether they just put it in DefinitelyTyped seeing that it is an open source framework.

Comment: Was propjet.d.ts hand written? I thought hand writing these was only necessary for libraries written originally in vanilla JavaScript and was hoping that it could be generated from TypeScript as part of the compilation.

Comment: Its entirely irrelevant to create d.ts file for a typescript library being consumed in a typescript project.

Comment: @DarkNeuron do you care to share how one would go about sharing a typescript library then in a way that is consumable by both JavaScript and TypeScript applications? Perhaps you know about a pattern that I do not?

Comment: Well sure, but if you need ES5 support, then there's no way around transpiling and generating the d.ts files. This is still easy to import in a TS project, and backwards compatibility is always good. :)

Answer (score 5):

To create a TS library that will be consumed by a TS project you don't have to do a whole lot.

*(Sorry if the example is overly verbose.)*

## The library

Assuming your source files are writting in TypeScript, you need the following config tweaks:

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/global",
    "typings/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

The important thing here is basically `declarations: true`, which tell the TS compiler to generate the d.ts files.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-typescript-library",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/my.service.js",
  "typings": "./dist/my.service.d.ts",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

The important things here is "main" and "typings" which is the entry point for the service in the library. So if someone were to `require("my-typescript-library")` then the file listed here would be used. The typings field is similar but obviously helps TypeScript.

You then push this library to Github, or Bitbucket, or where ever.

## The consumer

You don't need much here.

#### package.json

Add a dependency to your library:

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "my-typescript-library": "git+ssh://bitbucket.org/you/my-typescript-library",
    ...
  }
}
```

You will need an SSH key in this example.

Then you just import the lib.

#### my_file.ts

```
import {MyService} from "my-typescript-library";
```

So there you have it, a TypeScript lib being used in a TypeScript app. Hope that is enough of an answer (and clear enough), otherwise just drop me a line.

Answer (score -1):

well, I think that you can use modules for this purpose, modules is like namespace in c#, e.g.

```
//File Utils.ts
module Utils
{
    export class UtilsClass
    {
        do(param: string)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}

//Another ts file
var formatter = new Utils.UtilsClass();
formatter.do("str");
```

Regards,

Comment: Is there any way to have the module be packaged up for external use though? Think for example if I were to have a library like *underscore* written in TypeScript and I want to use it in various private projects in the company and perhaps also release it publicly at some point too. I would expect some way to export a d.ts definition file along with a .js JavaScript file as an option in the compiler.

Comment: But, this is only a ts file! (yes yes, a .js), so you can create a nuget packge or a npm package to share it like any other js library/framework... or maybe I dont undertand what is you need

Comment: My question isn't so much about whether it is possible it is about what is the expected conventional way of achieving this. TypeScript appears to be an ideal candidate language for creating JavaScript libraries but it appears that the main supported cases are TypeScript applications consuming vanilla JS libraries or vice versa but not TypeScript consuming TypeScript which to me is what I would expect to work the most naturally.