# Tutorial for creating custom typescript libraries

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am a relative newbie to node.js and typescript and am looking for tutorials and examples for building custom libraries for typescript.  I am currently working on a project(switched to WebStorm GUI) that requires I build several microservices and several of the microservices will need to share certain code, i.e., base repository functionality, etc.  My though would be to move the code they have in common to a series of separate libraries(projects) and make them into typings and have the projects that need them to install them.  Following the example I found here, and using grunt: [What is the story for creating and consuming TypeScript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012952/what-is-the-story-for-creating-and-consuming-typescript-libraries), I was able to generate the .js file and the .d.ts files in a dist folder on the project.  There are a few areas that I am confused about:

1) The example makes reference to a "main": "./dist/my.service.js" section in the jsconfig file, how necessary is this file and what should go into it?

2) If all of the files are transpiled and added to the dist folder, will the dependent code still be able to access it or do I have to transpile all of the files to root?

3) After I have have all of the file successfully transpiled and moved to the proper location, how do I install them to the dependent project if they are local and not up on the npm or Definitely Typed, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you would like to see an example project that I am currently working on that at the moment can be installed with npm is [binary-type-tree](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/binary-type-tree). There are some things I need to fix but overall the project is working great. You can see my setup for `Jest` in my [package.json](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/binary-type-tree/blob/master/package.json). Along with how to set up the types and the main.

Depending on what your library will be focused on you will want to choose the appropriate module system. Right now commonJS is the most common for npm packages. Although you can only compile to one file with system or amd.

As for compiling you do not need gulp/grunt you can use Webstorms IDE to compile your files. Simply open up the Webstorm settings "Languages and Frameworks" and select "Typescript" there you will see enable Typescript compiler.

> The example given is very old. Typescript had a major update to how typings work back in October of 2016, they moved to Typescript 2 I think, or maybe it was November. Anyway when you google search Typescript I would set the filter to not before that time.

### 1.

The `main` in the package.json of the Typescript project should point to the entry point of your library, or your executable. Since mine is a library it points to the compiled folder's index file. The file does not exist in my repo but it is there upon compilation.

### 2.

This I believe is answered depending on your build. In my build as an example I use module system `es6` as you can see in my [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/binary-type-tree/blob/master/tsconfig.json) file. This uses the ES6 module system.

> if you would like to use commonjs the structure of my project will still work properly except you will need something like Systemjs or Babel on the front end.

### 3.

This one is a bit unknown to me but what I have done for only testing is copy my directory into the node modules of another project I am working on. Now to require the project you do not need a @types since I have `"declaration": true` in my tsconfig.json file. The package.json of my project has a `"types":` section which points to the compiled `.d.ts` file. The project that is requiring this new TS package, if also written in TS, will have to have the `typeRoots` and `types` section in the tsconfig.json file. Once this is all set up you should be able to require it just fine.

> Make sure that the src of all your TS files is declared in the `includes` section of the tsconfig if your files are not compiled to root. Otherwise your project will have to require in files in an odd format like `import * as BTT from "lib/basic-node/avl-tree";`. Which is not what I wanted, once I added this it became `import * as BTT from 'binary-type-tree';`.

Answer (score 1):

The ["main" field in your package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) tells Node's module system what file to require when calling `require()`, so you will definitely need it. You point that field to a transpiled file, which will also contained transpiled references to your other transpiled TypeScript files, so you shouldn't have to add anything to root.

If you're trying to use the package from another project, you simply reference it as a dependency using NPM the same way you would with any other JS project.

```
{
  "name": "dependent-project",
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../typescript-project"
  }
}
```

Again, Node will know how to load the TypeScript project because you've specified the transpiled entry point in the `main` field.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you must consider:

In `package.json`, you must set some things up [(example)](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter/blob/master/package.json#L1):

- `main` property to point to your UMD compatible bundle
- `module` property for ES5 module. Then modern workflows can benefit from it, for example to apply [Tree Shaking](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/03/06/Tree-shaking-with-Webpack-2-TypeScript-and-Babel/)
- `typings` pointing to your `.d.ts` file (which should be generated)

That counts on a build process, which can be made with a module bundler, such as [RollupJS](https://rollupjs.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). They can generate source maps and so on.

As per question 3: you can install packages from local or even from Git repos. In your `package.json`, for example:

```
"your-library": "git+https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter.git"
```

I'd suggest you to take a look at [TypeScript Library Starter](https://github.com/alexjoverm/typescript-library-starter). You can find there everything you need. It has configured out of the box:

- Automatic releases
- Package.json configuration
- Universal module bundles
- Source Maps
- Typings (.d.ts) auto generated
- Docs using TypeDoc
- Tests and coverage